# Oscillations of a frame in a magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, harmonic-oscillator

Well, this is not *exactly* a homerwork question; nonetheless, I'd rather have it solved.

So, let's have a square frame of side $a$ and mass $m$ in a magnetic field $\vec{B}$ (look at the picture). There's a constant electric current $I$ flowing through the frame. The frame is initially inclined at angle $\alpha\ll 1$.

Find the period $T$ of the small oscillations the frame is gonna perform.

[image]

Well, in my understanding, the force acting on each of the two sides of the frame perpendicular to the field will be equal to:
$$ F=-BIa$$
Then, the total torque $M$ that is trying to rotate the frame:
$$ M=2F\frac{a}{2}\sin{\alpha}=-BIa^2\sin{\alpha}\approx-BIa^2\alpha$$
but I don't really know what should I do next. Well, the angular acceleration $\varepsilon$ is surely going to be:
$$ \varepsilon=\frac{M}{I_o},$$
where $I_o=\frac{ma^2}{6}$ is the moment of inertia of the frame. Then:
$$\varepsilon=-\frac{BIa^2\alpha}{ma^2/6} =-\frac{6BI}{m}\alpha$$
but what now? How can I calculate the period?

Comment: Your moment of inertia should be $ma^2/6$

Comment: You have derived an equation for simple harmonic motion.